# How to show modal popup upon submitting input button via ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, modal-dialog

When a user clicks on an input button, it'll pass certain values to the database. But, before this completes, I need to add a confirmation dialog via ajax.

```
<input type="button" class="finished" value="Next &raquo;" id="Save" />
 <div id="save-modal" class="modal-dialog">
    <div>
      <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>
      <h2>Done!</h2>
      <p>You just updated your profile.<br />Here is your new information!</p>
    </div>
 </div>​
```

This div is hidden by default:

```
            .modal-dialog {
                position: fixed;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                top: 0;
                right: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                left: 0;
                background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
                z-index: 99999;
                opacity:0;
                color: white;
                -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
                -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
                transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;
                pointer-events: none;
            }
            .modal-dialog:target {
                opacity:1;
                pointer-events: auto;
            }

            .modal-dialog > div {
                width: 230px;
                position: relative;
                margin: 10% auto;
                padding: 16px 20px 21px 20px;
                border-radius: 4px;
                background: #003c62;
                border: 2px white solid;
                box-shadow: inset 0 0 17px 3px rgba(127, 219, 248, .34) ,1px 1px 19px white;
            }
            modal-dialog h2 {
                font: 14px sans-serif;
                text-transform: uppercase;
            }
            .modal-dialog p {
                color: white;
                text-shadow: none;
                text-transform: none;
                font-size: 14px;
            }
            .close {
                background: #1E2D5C;
                color: white;
                line-height: 24px;
                position: absolute;
                right: -12px;
                text-align: center;
                top: -10px;
                width: 26px;
                text-decoration: none;
                font-weight: bold;
                border: 1px solid #666;
                border-radius: 12px;
                box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;
            }

            .close:hover { background: #00d9ff; }
```

​
And it should be done using $ajax()

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: baseUrl + '/Folder',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(values),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        error: function (xhr) {
            alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#save-modal').html(data);
        },
        async: true
    });
});
```

The modal works fine if you click `<a href="#save-modal">Modal</a>`, but I'd prefer not to use that.

What am I missing from the `success:` part of this `ajax()` function to make this work correctly?

Comment: Are you using a plugin for the modal? If you are you just need to tell the modal to open in the success callback. Check the plugin documentation on how to programmatically open the modal.
If no plugin used, $('#save-modal').show() ?

Comment: No plugin for the modal, it's CSS3 based. I'll try `.show()`. EDIT: tried `show()` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had a closer look, the modal is hidden by setting opacity to 0, put this in the success callback:

```
  $("#save-modal").css("opacity",1);
```

**EDIT:**

See here for updated example with AJAX request 
http://jsfiddle.net/xVDte/25/

In the CSS I added a class:

```
.modal-dialog.show{
    opacity:1;
    pointer-events:auto;
}
```

And then add and remove the show class for the success callback and close button

Comment: interesting, so that actually DID work but it doesn't transition in as stated in the CSS. It just pops up there suddenly. Am I going to have to include the transition property into the `css()` function too? And another strange thing is that this messes with the z-index whereas if I used the anchor tag, it works as intended.

Comment: Works fine here (in Firefox anyway), click the next button and it fades in
http://jsfiddle.net/xVDte/1/
I'd have the element fully hidden though, instead of just opacity:0; Also if you are using a library like jQuery, grab a modal plugin, it will do all of the hard stuff for you.

Comment: Right, and that would work properly since you're not using the `ajax()` function. Within that function, however, it doesn't behave properly. I'm assuming it has to go through the various properties of the `ajax()` function before it shows the div. And even then, the z-index isn't working right so it's not on top of everything else.

Comment: Okay, I realize now why this isn't working as well. I need the div to have the `:target` pseudo state and I hope I can find a way to do this using jQuery.

Comment: Wow, that worked! The transitions don't work still but it's functional so that's what matters. :)  Thanks so much!

Comment: Scratch what I said, the transitions weren't showing in my VM Windows Chrome browser but they appear in native OS browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If the data type of your AJAX request is JSON that means that the data argument to your success method should be an object not a string.  You would need to parse the object in your code and extract the HTML from whatever object members contain it.  Or if the PHP (or ASP) file handling this ajax request is returning raw HTML change your dataType:'html'.

```
success : function(data)
{
    // Use Chrome or Firefox and you can view this in the debug console.
    console.log(data);

    // We will assume that data.content is the HTML to fill the modal with.
    $("#save-modal").html(data.content);
},
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I tried this and the Console in Chrome just returns "OK". But nothing happens visually. And I can't change the dataType to raw HTML because it's calling a JSON function that's saving some data. That would mess up the actual function of this input. I'm trying to just add a step in between the page reload and submission.